# Android studio twitter check if user is logged in

Tags: java, android-studio, twitter, authentication, tweets

I have followed twitter fabric log in and everything is working fine except for the part where i try to post a tweet. When i execute this following code i need to login again, so it seems like i have to check an access token or some, but i have no idea and can't find how to do that.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //initialize facebook sdk
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
        String token = authToken.token;
        String secret = authToken.secret;

        if (token != null ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "twitter token" + token);
        }

        if (secret != null ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "twitter secret" + secret);
        }

        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this.getActivity(), new TwitterCore(authConfig), new TweetComposer());

}
```

then i am using a function to post the tweet

```
 public void TwitterSharing() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Running twitter share");

        Log.d(TAG, "Share on twitter 1: " + sport);
        Log.d(TAG, "Share on twitter 2: " + speed);
        Log.d(TAG, "Share on twitter 3: " + distance);
        Log.d(TAG, "Share on twitter 4: " + date);


        Log.d(TAG, "Shared image url: " + sharedImage);


        TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this.getActivity())
                .text("just setting up my Fabric.")
                .image(Uri.parse(sharedImage));
        builder.show();

    }
```

It all works but on the web page it is loading i need to login again, that should not happen but i have no idea how.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to make an `Activity` as the launcher activity. Let's call it `DispatchActivity`

```
public class DispatchActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        This returns true if user is logged in.
        boolean isLoggedIn = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
        if (isLoggedIn){
            //User is logged in, take him to your activity
            Intent i = new Intent(this,yourMainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(i);
        }
        else{
            //User is not logged in, take him to your SignIn activity
            Intent i = new Intent(this,SignUp.class);
            this.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to make this your launcher activity, and don't create a layout file for it.

Comment: i already have that part build. I have the problem with the part when the user levels my app to pot a tweet on twitter. Twitter ask the user to login again before they can post the tweet. The user should be logged in as they logged into my app already.

Comment: @carlosx2 my mistake.

Comment: that is ok, any input is welcome, i wonder if i am missing something as i can't find any other question regarding this topic.

Comment: @carlosx2  me neither, I'm not even familiar with Twitter Fabric

Comment: i hope some one else can help me with this. Thanks for putting your time into this.